# Can not git reset --hard origin/master

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo https://github.com/Glazomer/bem-react
I made lot of changes, but now I want to reset to origin/master or upstream/master (https://github.com/bem/bem-react)
I've tried:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git clean -f

git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git clean -f
```

Nothing helped! Files not reset to any of remotes...

Example:

```
ls ./packages/
classname   compose     di
classnames  core        eslint-plugin
```

But remotes structures are:

```
ls bem-react/packages/
classname   di
classnames  core        eslint-plugin
```

Comment: "Nothing helped", OK but what did you expect to happen? And what happened? Do you get error messages? Does the commands do something, just not quite what you had in mind?

Comment: Is the compose directory in your example part of any local commit? Or is it an untracked folder?

Comment: If you're on your own branch why don't you just check out to master? `git checkout master` and then `git pull`. If you made changes that you don't need anymore and everything's a mess, just clone the repo once again :-)

Comment: @vitkarpov hahaha, it pulled, but merged, so didn't help((

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't set up upstream. Check it out `.git/config`, should have something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:Glazomer/bem-react.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:bem/bem-react.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Best of luck!

Comment: No, everything is set up((